# Comparing integers and determining similarity

Tags: java, integer, compare

OK so I am writing a program that compares the number entered by a user to a computer generated number. Each number is 3 digits. What I'd like to know how to do is compare these integers. So for example if the last two digits of the three digit numbers are the same it will run a block of code. I'm not completely sure how to go about this. Any youtube videos or any links would be much appreciated. I would rather understand than get an answer to my code.

Comment: You can get last two digits of three digits number by calling modulo 100  operation on it, eg. ``123 % 100`` will result with 23. Then you can do the same for another number and just compare them. There are of course other ways like parsing ints to strings and comparing them, but modulo seems (for me at least) the way to go.

Comment: I was going to answer it but @Plebejusz 's comment is enough to tell you How you can get the answer.

Comment: comparing DIGITS of integerer (in base 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastet way would be: Convert the Integer to a String and then split the string at each char. Then you have an Char Array with each digit and you can compare them like whatever you want.

```
int number = 324;
String number_string = String.valueOf(number); //converts integer to string
char[] digits = number_string.toCharArray();   //converts string to char array
if(digits[2] == 4){                            //checks if 3rd digit of the char array is 4 
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get last two digit by modulo(%) operator.when you modulo three digit number by 100 it return last two digit and compare these digit in if condition like,

```
        int num=154; //number of three digit
        int rem=num%100;//modulo by 100 return remainder
        if(rem==54){ //checking condition 
            //code
        }
        else{
            //code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the number entered is a String so first you want to convert it to an integer.

```
String value = .... <whatever read from the user>
int number = Integer.parseInt(value)
```

Then, if you like to get information on some of the digits, use modulus, ie:

```
number%10
```

will give you the most right integer (ie 127%10 is 7)

```
number%100
```

will give you 2 digits (ie 626%100 is 26)